# CNAMEAlreadyExists when setting a wildcard CNAME in a CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cname

To move some CNAMEs from one distribution to another I am following [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-move) and when I add the wildcard *.mydomain.com CNAME I get a CNAMEAlreadyExists error.

I have checked all our distributions in this and all the other AWS accounts we own for *.mydomain.com but I can't find it duplicated. I've seen [this knowledge center article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cnamealreadyexists-error/) but don't have support, does anyone know how to find out where it's used or why it's refused?

> com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CNAMEAlreadyExistsException: One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 409; Error Code: CNAMEAlreadyExists; Request ID: bc0a9079-1432-11e9-a061-adf04e9fdb57)

Comment: You can't create the Alternate Domain Name wildcard `*.example.com` if any other AWS account has *anything* configured in CloudFront this wildcard also matches.  If account A has, for example, `www.example.com`, then account B cannot create `*.example.com` because that would potentially allow account B to hijack `www.example.com` if account A deleted their distribution.  So it doesn't have to be *exactly* the same for this error to occur.  Does this type of conflict describe a condition that exists across your accounts?

Comment: It definitely does, staging and test have subdomains that would match the wildcard. Thanks, that would be the answer.

Comment: Having the same issue. It worked a year ago when I had a wildcard domain (`*.example.com`) setup in addition to a separate distribution (`blog.example.com`). Kind of ridiculous AWS doesn't support this properly when I can proof I own all the domains.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is indeed possible. [The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) unambiguously states as much today. (emphasis mine)

> You cannot add an alternate domain name to a CloudFront distribution if the same alternate domain name already exists in another CloudFront distribution, even if your AWS account owns the other distribution.
>
> However, **you can add a wildcard alternate domain name, such as *.example.com, that includes (that overlaps with) a non-wildcard alternate domain name, such as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**. If you have overlapping alternate domain names in two distributions, CloudFront sends the request to the distribution with the more specific name match, regardless of the distribution that the DNS record points to. For example, marketing.domain.com is more specific than *.domain.com.

I encountered the same error while trying to do this allegedly supported configuration. After banging my head against the keyboard for an hour or so, I figured out the cause and a solution.

### The Cause

The following error occurs when CloudFront checks the DNS records for the new alias and sees the wildcard CNAME pointing to another distribution.

```
CNAMEAlreadyExists: One or more aliases specified for the distribution includes an 
incorrectly configured DNS record that points to another CloudFront distribution.
You must update the DNS record to correct the problem. For more information, see
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions
```

In this case, I'm guessing you have the following configured:

- You have a CloudFront distribution with a wildcard alias (eg, `*.example.com`). Let's call this `Distribution A`.
- You have a DNS record (in Route 53 or a third-party domain name service) mapping a CNAME from `*.example.com` to the endpoint for `Distribution A`.

Now, you are creating (or have already created) a second CloudFront distribution, `Distribution B`, and you are attempting to give it an overlapping alias such as `www.example.com`.

When we attempt to set the new alias on `Distribution B`, CloudFront does a DNS lookup for `www.example.com` and sees a CNAME mapping to `Distribution A`. This is considered invalid so the request is rejected with the error `CNAMEAlreadyExists`. (I think it is very unhelpful and confusing that AWS has overloaded this error message instead of returning a more accurate error.)

### The Solution

This error can be resolved by doing the following in order:

1. Create your second distribution, `Distribution B`. **Do not** configure the alias yet.
2. Create a CNAME DNS record mapping your overlapping alias (eg, `www.example.com`) to the endpoint for `Distribution B`.

   - Note: be sure to disable DNS features like Cloudflare's CNAME proxying which would obscure the target of the CNAME.
3. Now, configure the alias on `Distribution B`. This time it should succeed.